# response::download is doing nothing

Tags: laravel-4, download

I am having problems getting files to download outside of the public folder. Here is the Scenario:

These files cannot be accessed from anywhere but through this application and these downloads must go through access control. So a user can't download the file if they are not logged in and have permission to.

I have a route defined with a get variable. This ID goes into the controller and the controller calls the method below:

```
public static function downloadFile($id){
        $file = FileManager::find($id);

        //PDF file is stored under app/storage/files/
        $download= app_path().substr($file->location,6);///home/coursesupport/public_html/app/storage/files/fom01/7-2/activities-and-demos.pdf
        $fileName = substr($download,strrpos($download,'/')+1);//activities-and-demos.pdf
        $mime = mime_content_type($download);//application/pdf
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: '.$mime,
            "Content-Description" => "File Transfer",
            "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=" . $fileName
        );
        return Response::download($download, $fileName, $headers);
     }
```

the problem is it does nothing, just opens a blank page. Am I missing something? oh yeah, and the link to the route mentioned above opens a blank tab.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to not set those headers? Laravel does that for you already.

Answer (score 0):

It should work by doing only this:

```
public static function downloadFile($id)
{
    $file = FileManager::find($id);

    $download= app_path().substr($file->location,6);

    $fileName = substr($download,strrpos($download,'/')+1);

    return Response::download($download, $fileName);
 }
```

Comment: It has the same effect. :(

Comment: Does your file exists and your webserver has read access to it? What do you get in your server log files?

Comment: I was having file permission issues before. I'm going to look into this. thanks

Comment: What log files should i be looking in?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your route is actually returning the returned response. Eg:

```
Route::get('download', function()
{
    return DownloadHandler::downloadFile(1);
});
```

Without the `return` in the route the `IlluminateResponse` will do nothing.